# Get All Selected Nodes of Dev Components AdvanceTreeView Control

Tags: winforms, treeview, devexpress, multipleselection, dotnetbar

I am using Dev Components Advance TreeView controls in my C# Win Forms application. The tree view nodes have check boxes to select/deselect the node. I have enabled multiple selection of nodes in the tree view. I want to get all the selected nodes on "check/uncheck" of any node. I tried using treeview's "SelectedNodes" property that returns collection of Selected Nodes but some how it always returns "1" nod e.g. last selected Node.

***Update***
The problem is with selection of Children Nodes. If I multi select all the parent nodes then I get the right count back but in case of Children Nodes the count is always 1
Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple recursive function, just pass the root node in here. If you don't want recursion, hook a selected node list into the event handler for check/uncheck.

```
     static public List<HierarchyNode> GetCheckedNodes(HierarchyNode node)
    {
        var nodes = new List<HierarchyNode>();

        foreach (HierarchyNode childNode in node.Nodes)
        {
            nodes.AddRange(GetCheckedNodes(childNode));
        }

        if (node.Checked)
        {
            nodes.Add(node);
        }

        return nodes;
    }
```